# Multiplying Binary Numbers in Python

Tags: python, binary

Lets say I have the binary number 0b110, which is 6, and I want to multiply the number by 3, to get 18 which is 0b10010. How would I do that in Python, I tried multiplying it normally, but it didn't work...

Comment: Won't typecasting binary to int and then back do the trick?

Comment: "_I tried multiplying it normally_" - not sure what you mean by that. First off, do you know how to multiply in binary (without any specific language)?

Comment: @skytreader: binary numbers are ints, decimal numbers are ints, Xary numbers are ints, no need to cast.

Comment: @NiklasB. Fair point. I was thinking OP wanted results displayed in 0s and 1s _representation_ though. Hence, the typecasting.

Comment: What did you try? What was your expected output? What was your actual output?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
>>> 0b110 * 0b11
18
>>> bin(0b110 * 0b11)
'0b10010'
```

Comment: Haha, this is easily earned reputation :P

Answer (score 3):

```
In [2]: 0b110 * 3
Out[2]: 18

In [3]: bin(0b110 * 3)
Out[3]: '0b10010'
```